# Creating Instance of an unknown Class from a non-GAC Assembly

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-assembly

Sounds like a dumb question I know, but bear with me :-)  I'm currently creating a PoSh module which contains a few custom commands.  I had already written a PoSh Advanced Module previously to do what I want to do, but I've decided it's time to take the plunge and learn C# !

One of my commands needs to create an instance of a class which is contained in a third party SDK assembly.  That assembly is not contained in the GAC.  In my PoSh Advanced Function previously, I would query a registry key to confirm that the SDK was installed (and get the path to it), then I would use System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile to load the assembly.

In my C# version, my plan was to do something similar.  I've managed to query the registry, confirm that the assembly exists etc and even load it.  However, because the assembly isn't referenced in Visual Studio, it just throws loads of intellisense errors when I try to instantiate a class from that assembly.  I initially suspected I might need to use something from the Activator class to get around this, but I've been through all the methods there and couldn't find anything that might help.

After a bit more pondering, I wondered if perhaps my approach is wrong, and maybe I shouldn't be doing the "manual" loading but instead allow .net handle all that for me, eg by adding a reference to the assembly.  In that case however, how do I reference an assembly in VS without knowing where (or even if) it will be installed on the target/invoking machine ?

Or, if my original approach is correct, how do instantiate the class "manually" (or otherwise) without VS being so unhappy.  I did consider adding a "temporary" reference to the assembly on my machine, but I think I'd have to remove that again before doing the retail build.  And I'd also have to add temporary using directives I guess.

I have googled this quite a bit, but haven't found anything that might help me at all.  So I'd really appreciate any guidance anybody can provide.  Maybe I should be looking at something else entirely, like App Domains ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried yet to attach the dll as embedded resource ?

Comment: I've no experience with embedded resources, but from a quick google I guess they are basically assemblies that I "bundle" with my solution, right ?  That wouldn't work in my case because the SDK in the 3rd party assembly provides an interface into their application.  The SDK assembly is installed as part of the application, so bundling the assembly with my module wouldn't be of any value as I'd still be dependent on the application being installed also.  But thanks for the comment, it all helps when you're a newbie like me :-)

Answer (score 0):

After loading assembly use `CreateInstance` method and store result in `dynamic` type variable:

```
dynamic test = assembly.CreateInstance("Full.Type.Name");
```

You'll not get intellisense, but compiler will assume that this variable supports any operation. Beware, invalid operations will result in errors only at runtime.

Comment: >> You'll not get intellisense, but compiler will assume that this variable supports any operation. Beware, invalid operations will result in errors only at runtime.

Yup, I had expected alright that I wouldn't get intellisense and would just have to "manually" ensure everything myself.  Thanks for the tip, I'll try that out and post back